# Javascript fails to load, inaccessible path

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am getting following error when I try to open any page.

Error: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException:

The script

```
http::/../ScriptResource.axd?d=3BNDLY2l6G1FISJHhotvdhh_kMSuOckQ8W-RY1rEnIVGD7fal1mO7_SthKIZEtK5EfrJjroEOA9m3ARUWf3PRvgXjDSvslrVJ81MMptm-ZsJT-Uie8FWjGTWUcAfXiSGvW4hKbDVMtTVZaR-1wAUV1B3gc81&t=ffffffff9b7d03cf
```

failed to load. Check for:Inaccessible path.

Please suggest to me a solution for this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution I got,

just clear all browser history and restart browser,and this works.